# Как сделать эти круги адаптивными?

Tags: javascript, html, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Помогите сделать эти круги адаптивными, чтобы при уменьшении экрана - они могли красиво уезжать в низ и не превращаться в кашу. Позиционирование кругов статичное, так же если вы хотите можете поменять на абсолютное.

Вот мой небольшой "говно код":

```
<https://codepen.io/Persovt/pen/WNwvmaO>
```

Comment: Это лучше сделать на canvas

Comment: Ты можешь сделать элементы по ширине и высоте(!) относительно ширины экрана пользователя vw. Смотри https://html5book.ru/edinicy-izmereniya-vh-vw-vmin-vmax/

Comment: добавьте `flex-wrap: wrap;` в `.statistic`, а далее можно будет применить медиа-запросы для коррекции

Comment: @h, можете привести примем на canvas. Тоже думал над реализацией задачи этим методом.